# Django: How to get user full name from user id

Tags: django, django-models

My model:

```
author=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

User id (ex. 174948) is saved to column `author_id`.
In the template I show user id with `{{post.author}}`
I want also to show full name for that particular user.
How to do that in the template?

Answer (score 14):

By using the method that does it.

```
{{post.author.get_full_name}}
```

Comment: For some reason that does not work.It does not show anything.

Comment: @user3760940: I got the wrong method. Try this one.

Comment: I guess that is the correct way but still it does not show anything.

Comment: @user3760940: Is `User` `django.contrib.auth.User`?

Comment: If you mean this from django.contrib.auth.models import User   then yes

Answer (score 11):

It depends if the user object has the first and/or last name fields set.

If not (for example a new user was just created), then calling `{{ post.author.get_full_name }}` may return an empty string.

This method is more reliable:

```
{{ post.author.get_full_name|default:post.author.username }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
{{post.author.first_name}} {{post.author.last_name}}
```